# Remove placeholder unless it contains something between the parentheses

Tags: php, regex

I have a basic template class that replaces placeholders with data, but if a placeholder doesn't get replaced I replace it with an empty string.

I am having issues with templates that contain jQuery though. It see some jquery statements as placeholders and removes them making the javascript invalid.

Currently this is what I use to remove placeholders that weren't perviously replaced:

```
preg_replace("/\\$[^\"' \|\[]+?;/", "", $tmp);
```

It successfully replaces this `$get.q.htmlentities();` with an empty string (which is good), but for javascript like the following, it removes everything after the equal sign.

```
var val = $(this).val();
var me = $(this);
```

What I think the best solution would be is to ignore anything that has a value between the parentheses, but I am not sure how to add that to my current `preg_replace` statement. What could I do to add this, or is there something better I could do?

**Placeholder Format**

Placeholders have a few formats:

- starts with a `$` and ends with a `;`
- Placeholders can only contain `a-zA-Z0-9`, `.`, `_`, `(` and `)`
- Can not contain spaces between the `$` and the `;`
- A `(` may not come after the `$`
- Nothing may be between the parentheses

Valid examples (replace with empty string):

```
$placeholder;
$get.q.htmlentities().json_encode();
```

Invalid examples (leave it alone):

```
$(this).placeholder();
$()placeholder;
$10.00 per/hr;
```

Comment: Why not replace it with `"''"` instead of just `""`?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, or how that would help. Sorry.

Comment: You can always add `(?<!=|= )` at the beginning of your expression ...

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV could you add an example please?

Comment: @RyanNaddy `(?<!=|= )\$[^\"' \|\[]+?;` This means match your expression if there is **no** `=` or `=space` before it [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/lF8pJ9). But maybe this expression would be better `\$[^\(\)]+\(\)` [demo](http://regex101.com/r/xY8iY4)?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV it seems to work. Add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments here's a workaround:
`(?<!=|= )\$[^\"' \|\[]+?;`: We added `(?<!=|= )` to prevent matches that are followed by `=` or `={space}`.
**[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/lF8pJ9)**.

The above regex is ofcourse not that good since it would fail if there are more spaces for example. So here's a completely new approach:
`\$[^\(\);]+(?:\(\))?(?:\.[^\(\)]+(?:\(\))?)*?;`

**[Explanation](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5C%24%5B%5E%5C%28%5C%29%3B%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%5C%28%5C%29%29%3F%28%3F%3A%5C.%5B%5E%5C%28%5C%29%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%5C%28%5C%29%29%3F%29%2a%3F%3B)**

**[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/jP6zI6)**.

Comment: the second one doesn't work, because it doesn't match items like `$placeholder;`, the first one does catch those. http://regex101.com/r/jV6pY8

Comment: Sorry for being so picky, but it doesn't catch this `$get.q.htmlentities().func2();` but it does catch everything else!

Comment: @RyanNaddy Haha no problem, [demo](http://regex101.com/r/jP6zI6) you may report any further problems.

Comment: I like that one! It does what I need! Thanks!